# Angular upload image from mobile browser doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a simple angular 5 application that uploads an image to my server. The problem is that in desktop browsers it works without problems, but when I'm going to upload images from a mobile device this does not work.

Then I show my Angular code:
[Online Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vuufdb)

When I try to use this web app from mobile safari (V11) the blank screen appears, in google chrome mobile it works, but if I upload a heavy image ... it does not upload anything to my server.

My question is how can I do this, so that it works in both safari and chrome (Desktop / mobile)...this is the idea of ​​a web application.

Thanks

Comment: there you have it. this is probably a browser problem. check the browser support for the Angular version you're using

Comment: [https://angular.io/guide/browser-support](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support)

Comment: Hi, where you able to fix the issue